# Theme isn't applying in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to apply a specific theme on a Fragment. But for some reason it isn't happening. Can anyone point out mistakes in my code? Or better solutions?

Theme in styles.xml:

```
<!-- Theme for trans actionbar -->
<style name="TransTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TransActionbar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/TransActionbar</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Where `@style/TransActionbar` is:

```
<!-- Actionbar style for trans theme -->
<style name="TransActionbar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/first_trans_actionbar</item>
    <item name="background">@color/first_trans_actionbar</item>
</style>
```

How I want to apply the theme in my fragment in the `onCreateView()` method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //set theme
    final Context contextWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.TransTheme);
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextWrapper);
    contentView = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_detail,
            container, false);
    return contentView:
}
```

For some reason the Fragment keeps the old theme..

**Edit**

So basically the question comes down to: How do you make an Actionbar transparent (and overlay mode) in just one fragment of an activity?

Comment: Are you applying your theme in the manifest?

Comment: @Sassa I am trying to change the theme that is applied in the manifest as soon as I navigate to a different  fragment.

Comment: I see; are you applying the original theme in the `application` or in the `activity` tag in the manifest?

Comment: @Sassa There is an overall theme applied in the application tag, I try to override that theme with the above code. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the `ActionBar` and not with the whole theme. For example, can you try changing the background color in `TransTheme`? That should probably work. Are you extending from `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: @Sassa I've tried changing the color, but it stays the same. I'm not extending from ActionBarActivity since im not using the v21 support library, so that isn't necessary then right?

Comment: The ContextThemeWrapper approach works for the views created in onCreateView but the ActionBar is likely not part of that view hierarchy. If you want this to work you'd need to use your own Toolbar implementation (Toolbar or ActionMenuView from the support library).

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin Would this be compatible with pre lollipop devices?

Comment: Toolbar is part of the v7 support library so yes it would work from Android 2.1.x on.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin I guess that would be a good workaround then. Thanks!

Comment: what `parent = "AppTheme"` means?

Comment: @Xcihnegn It's a reference to a theme that inherits from the base holo theme.

Comment: Ok should be like that `"parent=@style/AppTheme"`?

Comment: @Xcihnegn Yea, sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: why you are not mentioning theme in manifest

Comment: @apk It is mentioned in the manifest..

Comment: final Context contextWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.TransTheme);
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextWrapper); whats this for

Comment: @apk That is an attempt to change the theme. And inflate the layout using the context of a different theme than the original theme in the manifest. But it didn't work..

Comment: so do you want fragments theme different than activity is it so?

Comment: @apk Yes. At runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you want to be switching two (or more) `Fragment`s within the same `Activity`, where each of them could require the `ActionBar` to either be overlaid or not, and have different backgrounds depending on the current `Fragment`.

Let's get the most important thing out of the way: **as of yet, you can't change an `Activity`'s theme at runtime.**

You can still relatively easily accomplish what you are after by doing the following:

1. Set the `Activity` theme to use an overlaid `ActionBar`.
2. For those `Fragment`s where you don't want the `ActionBar` to be overlaid, in their layout xml, set a top padding/margin equal to the `ActionBar` height. Ideally you would just reference [the dimension resource for action bar height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26491690). For those `Fragment`s where you want the `ActionBar` to overlay them, you should just have no padding/margin at the top of their layout xml.
3. When you switch `Fragment`s, change the background color of the `ActionBar` by calling `getActionBar()` (or `getSupportActionBar` if you are using the support library) and then `.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` or whatever color you need from the resources using `getResources().getColor(R.colors.some_color)`. You could go for something more fancy than an abrupt switch, by animating the color change, but that's beyond the scope of this question.
4. ...
5. Profit!

**EDIT: With `Toolbar`**

If you want to use a `Toolbar`, the way to do it would be to put it in a separate layout xml that you `<include>` inside your `Activity` layout and give it some ID that you can reference through code. Make sure the `Activity` root layout is something with Z ordering, like `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`, and position the toolbar `<include>` at the top of the Y axis (`alignParentTop` for `RelativeLayout` or `layout_gravity="top"` for `FrameLayout`), **and** put the `Toolbar` `<include>` after whatever layout you will be putting your `Fragment`s inside, so that it will overlay them.

Inside the `Activity` `onCreate` do this:

```
Toolbar yourToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar);
yourToolbar.setBackgroundColor(<whatever color you want>);
setSupportActionBar(yourToolbar);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true/false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true/false);
actionBar.setTitle(<whatever title you want>);
```

Otherwise, everything from my original answer still holds.

Comment: This is a really good suggestion! What would you recommend: using this solution or the Toolbar?

Comment: I'll update my answer to clarify how this meshes with a Toolbar :)

Answer (score 6):

thanks to Tomask https://stackoverflow.com/a/34686405/5502121 
You can change attributes in Activity Theme of a fragment in runtime. Just overwrite them before fragment was inflated with your custom style and apply to a current Theme:

1. Say, you have some attributes that you want to apply in your fragment, for example ripple color. Make a style with this attribute:
   in **values/styles.xml**

   ```
   <style name="colorControlHighlight_blue">
      <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/main_blue_alpha26</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. In your fragment before inflation in `onCreateView()`

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      getContext().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.colorControlHighlight_blue, true); //blue ripple color
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
      return view;
   }
   ```

This style will work only for this fragment

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution,

If you just want to apply style for specific Fragment of Activity then just add this lines before calling `onCreateView()` or `onAttach()` of the Fragment,

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

and set transparent status bar then set **false** to `fitsSystemWindows` property of your root layout,

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

It works for me, hope it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the changes [here](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) of the support library 22.1, I have seen that you can now apply a theme to any view (this also implies that it can be applied to a fragment). So I believe if you use the new appcompat and set the desired theme to your fragment's root view, it will do the trick.

But as I can see that you are trying to change the style of the ActionBar... I don't think this will work, because the ActionBar is created by your Activity and not your fragment, so it takes the style from your Activity. You would need to change the theme in your Activity in order to do that.

Comment: I am trying to change the theme of my activity in the onCreateView() method using the ContextWrapper. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Of course it won't. Activity is already created by the time onCreateView is called as it is the Activity who is creating the fragment  (not the way arround) and you cannot change the theme once the activity is already created. You would need to reload the whole activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635824/change-activity-theme-deppending-on-fragment-in-use-android

Comment: I was under the impression that when you inflate the fragment with a ContextWrapper that wraps a new theme, it would inflate the fragment using that theme. What would be a different way to achieve this then? Basically, if I can make the Actionbar transparent as soon as that specific fragment loads, it would be fine.

Comment: You need it to be transparent or you would like to hide it completely?

Comment: I need it transparent. I've tried the other SO question but it doesn't seem to work either. I set my actionbar colors to the same values as in the question and change the window colors to the exact same color (Color.WHITE), and nothing happens. Plus I don't know if that would even work for transparent, because what color combination gives a transparent actionbar?

Comment: Every color gives a transparent color if you set it's opacity bits to 00 -> ActionBar bar = getActivity().getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00000000"))); does this work?

Comment: Nope :/, it changes it to a black actionbar. Even if it would make the actionbar transparent, it wouldn't overlay the view.

Comment: Result it totally white, since the actionbar can't be transparent if it isn't in overlay mode I think...

Comment: You need to enable it. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html If that doesn't help, you should be considering in using a Toolbar

Comment: The problem with overlay mode is.. It has to be applied in a theme.. I can't switch themes because the activity is already started..

Comment: I know. Apply it to your activity and you will make it transparent when you need it to be (in your fragment)

Comment: But I don't want my actionbar to be in overlay mode in the entire activity.. Just in that one fragment. Oh and btw, thanks for your help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should apply theme to your activity instead of fragment.

try setTheme(R.style.TransTheme); above setContentView();

Comment: The problem here is that I don't want the Activity theme to be R.style.TransTheme, just one fragment inside that activity.